# Any way to split two different strings using one c# method?

Tags: c#, string, split

I have two Strings. For which the output required is as follows.

1. Input : "Abc (1.23)(12a/b)"
   Output : "Abc (1.23)"
2. Input : "Abc(12a/b)"
   Output : "Abc"

I am using C#.
I used string.Split("(")[0]. This gives me output for second but not for first requirement.
I need an equation that works for both. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: var a = yourString.Replace("(12a/b)", string.Empty);

Comment: Could you, please, explain the required ouput? What is the desired result for, say, `"Abc(1.2345)(15.7)"`? And why?

Comment: Hi SBFrancies, thanks but what if the substring (12a/b) is different for different strings. But the para thesis are present. Is there any other way?

Comment: Hi Dmitry Bychenko, It is just a required output. There is no logic or calculation required for generating the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result1 = Remove12aSlashb("Abc (1.23)(12a/b)");
        var result2 = Remove12aSlashb("Abc(12a/b)");
    }

    public static string Remove12aSlashb(string str)
    {
        return str.Replace("(12a/b)", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you are actually trying to do (from your example strings) is to chop off the last set of text in parenthesis. If so, then `string.Split("(")` can still do it, but then you need to combine the results with a slightly more complicated logic.
Something like this could do it.

```
public static string RemoveFinalParens(string str) {
        var pieces=str.Split("(");
        string retString=null;
        for (int i=0;i<pieces.Count;i++) {
           return+=pieces[i];
           if ((i+1)<pieces.Count) {return+="("};
        }
        return retString;
    }
```